# creating a fast android dictionary (word counts)

Tags: java, android, performance, sqlite, dictionary

I am currently working on an application for various **statistics**.
One task is to analyse a good amount of sentences for their wordcounts.

**the specifications are:**

- sentences are read from SQLiteDatabase (up to 20k with an average of about 15 words)
- transformation: split by whitespaces (to get the words of the sentences)
- transformation: toLowerCase (to minimize variations of words)
- transformation: replace [^a-zA-Z] (for the same reason as above)
- get word + count for the first x (not sure yet, maybe 10-15) most common words
- preserve a flag if the messages was sent/received

This is my current approach:

```
db.execSQL("create temp table if not exists WORDS (WORD varchar, SENT integer)");
Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("select lower(MSG) as SENTENCE, SENT from MESSAGELIST",null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String[] words = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("SENTENCE")).split(
                "\\s+");
        int from_me = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("SENT"));
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            words[i] = words[i].replaceAll("[^a-zA-z]", "");
            if (!words[i].equals("")) {
                db.execSQL("insert into WORDS values ('" + words[i] + "', "
                        + from_me + ")");
            }
        }
    }
    Cursor c2 = db.rawQuery(
            "select WORD, COUNT(*) as CNT from WORDS where SENT=0 group by WORD order by CNT desc limit 10",
            null);
    Cursor c3 = db.rawQuery(
            "select WORD, COUNT(*) as CNT from WORDS where SENT=1 group by WORD order by CNT desc limit 10",
            null);
```

As I already assumed this code is pretty slow. I guess the string manipulation takes a lot of time.

It also feels wrong to extract from and reenter into a db just for the query. However, I know there is `regexp_split_to_array` and `regexp_split_to_table` in `PostgreSQL` which would make it possible to stay on the database for the query. I have yet to find a solution to do this in `SQLite`

**I have spent a good amount of time trying to figure out different solutions but I´m kinda stuck now. Is there any (relativly) fast method to perform the required tasks? I´m also open for suggestions to make the wordcount as reasonable as possible.**

**Current version with some of the suggested implementations:**

Improvements:

- Prepared Statements: ~29% faster
- Precompiling the regular expressions: ~21% faster
- the commented section indicate my implementation of counts but this approach raised the runtime (with and without index)
- bulk inserting via transaction: ~ 9% faster
- CharMatcher for replacement: ~8% faster
- HashMultiset for counting: ~2% faster

  ```
  c = db.rawQuery("select lower(DATA) as SENTENCE, SENT from MESSAGELIST", null);

  CharMatcher pat_rep = CharMatcher.inRange('A', 'Z')
          .or(CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z')).precomputed();
  Pattern pat_split = Pattern.compile("\\s");
  HashMultiset<String> sent = HashMultiset.create();
  HashMultiset<String> rcvd = HashMultiset.create();

  while (c.moveToNext()) {
      String[] words = pat_split.split(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("SENTENCE")));
      int from_me = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("SENT"));

      for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
          words[i] = pat_rep.retainFrom(words[i]);
          if (!words[i].equals("")) {
              if (from_me == 1) {
                  sent.add(words[i]);
              } else {
                  rcvd.add(words[i]);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  db.execSQL("create temp table if not exists WORDS (WORD varchar, SENT integer, CNT integer)");
  SQLiteStatement ins = db.compileStatement("insert into WORDS values (?, ?, ?)");
  db.beginTransaction();

  Iterator<String> i = sent.iterator();
  while (i.hasNext()) {
      String in = i.next();
      ins.bindString(1, in);
      ins.bindLong(2, 1);
      ins.bindLong(3, sent.count(in));
      ins.executeInsert();
      ins.clearBindings();
  }
  i = rcvd.iterator();
  while (i.hasNext()) {
      String in = i.next();
      ins.bindString(1, in);
      ins.bindLong(2, 0);
      ins.bindLong(3, rcvd.count(in));
      ins.executeInsert();
      ins.clearBindings();
  }
  db.setTransactionSuccessful();
  db.endTransaction();
  c = db.rawQuery(
          "select WORD, CNT from WORDS where SENT=0 group by WORD order by CNT desc limit 10",
          null);
  Cursor c2 = db.rawQuery(
          "select WORD, CNT from WORDS where SENT=1 group by WORD order by CNT desc limit 10",
          null);
  ```

Comment: Why does this database exist only on the app if you want to do complex statistics calculations? Can you not just send it to your server?

Comment: @Falmarri: I want the application to run offline, because there is no server to send it to (as of right now) ;) also: what would be the benefit except for making use of the servers' performance?

Comment: You have to put some index on your `msg` and `word` columns, especially if you have lots of records in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.execSQL("insert into WORDS values ('" + words[i] + "', "
                    + from_me + ")");
```

Too much DB access. Hitting the DB for every single word can't go well. As many words are repeated, you can count them in a [Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultiset.html) and store together with their count, when the memory gets tight or when you're done.

It also makes no sense to create a separate row for each occurrence. Add a column `count` (better call it differently as "count" is a keyword).

Use prepared statements. By creating a query string every time, you force the DB to parse it again and again. And also produce work for the GC.

```
words[i] = words[i].replaceAll("[^a-zA-z]", "");
```

Use [Pattern.compile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)) or [CharMatcher](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html). The latter produces no garbage in the common case of no special chars.

```
private final CharMatcher alpha = CharMatcher.inRange('A', 'Z')
        .or(CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z')).precomputed();

alpha.retainFrom(words[i]);
```

This should help a lot, especially the DB stuff. Try it out and come again if it's not enough.

Comment: thanks alot for the input, I implemented some stuff (see updated question) and already got quite a performance boost! I have yet to try the Guava library stuff.

Comment: @MazePutze The `CharMatcher` is a useful thing but this use case is not important enough for using a library. OTOH Guava is just fantastic and it's worth learning and using. Feel free to post a follow-up question if you need more improvements. I guess, [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) would be more appropriate. Don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: I added the library and got another 10% improvement for the CharMatcher AND the HashMultiset which justifies the library usage I guess. In total I´m at about 70% faster execution which is already a really greate help. But if there are any more suggestions for improvements or better implementations for using e.g. the hashmultiset I´d appreciate more input. Thank you!

Comment: @MazePutze As said, feel free to post your improved code on [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). You'll get much more directed answers when we see your new code.

Comment: did that [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60579/creating-a-fast-android-dictionary-word-counts)!

Comment: @MazePutze And I answered it. Does "70% faster execution" mean a ratio of 1.00 to 1.70 (i.e., just a bit) or 1.00 to 0.30, (i.e., about threefold)? I always prefer to say the factor as it's unambiguous.

Comment: my bad, it is 1.00 to 0.30, my selected testcase came down from about 25.5s to roughly 7.5s